# Dropzone.js Como recibo un ID desde la BD antes de que se termine de cargar un archivo?

Tags: php, dropzone.js

tengo una situación que he intentado solucionar de varias maneras y no me ha resultado.

Lo que necesito es que al comenzar el upload de un video, pueda crear un ID en la base de datos y retornarlo hacia el evento de Dropzone **sending** para enviarlo junto a los otros campos de formulario. Necesito el ID, porque mientras el video se esté subiendo, tengo que mostrar una vista previa de lo que se guardó en la base de datos y el usuario pueda modificar el nombre del video.

Para crear el ID en la BD tengo esta función ajax:

```
function create() {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: urlroot + 'Videos/id',
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
            myCallback(response);
        }
    });
    return result;
}

function myCallback(response) {
    return response;
}
```

Y este es el evento sending de Dropzone:

```
this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
    var idv = create();
    formData.append("id", idv);
    formData.append("artistas", jQuery("#artistas").val());
    formData.append("artistas", jQuery("#artistas").val());
});
```

El problema es que la respuesta $ajax no alcanza a llegar antes de que el evento **sending** se ejecute, así que mi **"idv"** entra como "undefined" al script php. Entiendo que es por la llamada asyncrona. Intenté retrasar de alguna forma la ejecución de sending (con promesas o setTimeOut) pero no funciona.

Intenté también crear directamente en el script php de upload, el ID en la BD y retornarlo con "return" o con "echo", pero la respuesta sólo la puedo recibir en el evento "success" y yo necesito que puedan modificar el nombre del video mientras se esté subiendo al server.

También traté de acceder en el evento "sending" a la data del objeto file o del xhr y con console.log me muestra el .responseText, pero cuando deseo acceder directamente me dice que está vacio:

```
console.log(file.xhr.responseText);
console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

Ya no se que mas intentar, necesito ese ID para modificar el dato en la base mientras se esté subiendo el archivo, ya que el nombre del video se puede repetir. Talvez debo cambiar mi enfoque, si alguien me ilumina se agradecería un montón.

Estoy atenta a sus comentarios,

Comment: Revisando la [lista de eventos disponibles](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list), deberías usar `success` para crear el contenedor solo cuando el archivo se subió correctamente y, tal vez, una combinación de `sending` y `uploadprogress` para mostrar el avance.

Comment: Lamentablemente no me sirve success, porque lo que necesitan es que mientras el archivo se esté procesando poder actualizar el nombre del video o cualquier otro dato que ya se guardó en la base de datos.

Comment: Entonces, vas a tener que ejecutar 2 peticiones, la primera, enviando solo datos, incluyendo nombre del archivo y, cuando finalice, usar la información de la respuesta (id, nombre, etc.) para ejecutar la segunda petición que solo subirá el archivo.